# BSOD when connected to internet via Ethernet

Tags: windows-10, networking, bsod, wired-networking

**Problem definition**

I am using Windows 10 on a Lenovo laptop with a Realtek network card. The network card shows in the Device Manager as "Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller" and I usually connect to the internet using Ethernet. This worked fine for 3/4 years. Since a few days, after 30s-90s of being connected to the internet via Ethernet I get a BSOD and the PC restarts.

**What I did (and did not solve the problem)**

1. I convinced myself this was an IP address conflict problem. I have static IP address, but can change to dynamic. I did it, but after the canonical 30s-90s the PC showed the BSOD and rebooted.
2. I downloaded the latest drivers from the vendors website. I have now Driver version 10.62.824.2022 from 24/08/2022.
3. According to the suggestion of [DrMoishe Pippik](https://superuser.com/users/401553/drmoishe-pippik), I used [Windows DISM and SFC utilities](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image) to check for system file issues. DISM did not find any issue. SFC found and fixed some issues, but this did not resolve the BSOD problem.
4. According to the suggestion of [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound), I updated to Windows 10 22H2. After that, I plugged the Ethernet cable. After a few minutes... BSOD again.
5. According to the suggestion of [Daniel B](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b) I disabled the wi-fi card (Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160) while connecting to Ethernet. After a few minutes... Same story. (You may notice that we are now talking about minutes and not 30s-90s.
6. According to the suggestion of [SkylicC](https://superuser.com/users/94557/sylikc) I started updating some drivers. Since I already updated the Ethernet card drivers, keeping in mind the observation of [Daniel B](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b) that the issue may be caused by the Wi-Fi, I decided to start by updating the Wi-Fi driver. It is now version 18.33.17.1 from 29/04/2019, replacing a version from 2016 or something. After a few minutes... BSOD.
7. According to the suggestion of [John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john), I disabled my ethernet card and connected via a USB LAN Network card. Same story.

**Info I extracted**

I executed WinDbg (just because I read it can be useful) with the hope that someone understands what's going on:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25200.1003 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff803`37200000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff803`37e2a2b0
Debug session time: Wed Nov 23 13:40:22.028 2022 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 4:56:48.766
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
...............................................................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
.......................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff803`375f92d0 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:0018:fffff803`3c67ee20=0000000000000133
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above.
Arg2: 0000000000001e00, The watchdog period (in ticks).
Arg3: fffff80337efb320, cast to nt!DPC_WATCHDOG_GLOBAL_TRIAGE_BLOCK, which contains
    additional information regarding the cumulative timeout
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: TickPeriods                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 6936

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 965324

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 14

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 23

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 1531

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 473411

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 110

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.DumpHeader
    Value: 0x133

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.KiBugCheckData
    Value: 0x133

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.Register
    Value: 0x133

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY.DMP

BUGCHECK_CODE:  133

BUGCHECK_P1: 1

BUGCHECK_P2: 1e00

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff80337efb320

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

TRAP_FRAME:  ffff9a84bf4ae1f0 -- (.trap 0xffff9a84bf4ae1f0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=00000001d20c0002 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffff80337e59740
rdx=fffffffffffffff0 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80337602907 rsp=ffff9a84bf4ae380 rbp=ffff9a84bf4ae471
 r8=fffffffffffffff0  r9=0000000000000000 r10=fffff80337e59740
r11=ffff8dffc5000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
nt!ExpInterlockedPopEntrySListFault:
fffff803`37602907 498b08          mov     rcx,qword ptr [r8] ds:ffffffff`fffffff0=????????????????
Resetting default scope

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff803`3c67ee18 fffff803`3765bf02     : 00000000`00000133 00000000`00000001 00000000`00001e00 fffff803`37efb320 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff803`3c67ee20 fffff803`374d2973     : 00002d47`78984ce4 fffff803`33f87180 00000000`00000000 fffff803`33f87180 : nt!KeAccumulateTicks+0x186d32
fffff803`3c67ee80 fffff803`374d245a     : fffff803`37ef3880 ffff9a84`bf4adf00 fffff803`3ca8d800 00000000`0000a201 : nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x453
fffff803`3c67ef30 fffff803`37408a45     : fffff803`37ef3880 fffff803`3c67ef40 00000000`00000010 ffff959c`76c911b0 : nt!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine+0x1a
fffff803`3c67ef60 fffff803`375fb26a     : ffff9a84`bf4adf00 fffff803`37ef3880 00000000`00000200 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xa5
fffff803`3c67efb0 fffff803`375fba37     : fffff71b`f5e422c0 fffff803`3752300a ffff9a84`00000000 ffffffff`fffffff0 : nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xfa
ffff9a84`bf4ade80 fffff803`3760d3ad     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`bf4ae270 ffffffff`ffffffd2 fffff803`3743962f : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37
ffff9a84`bf4ae010 fffff803`37608ebd     : fffff803`37e59740 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0x6d
ffff9a84`bf4ae1f0 fffff803`37602907     : fffff803`37e59740 fffff803`37427b0f ffffd607`834c9b20 ffffd607`88b83dc0 : nt!KiPageFault+0x43d
ffff9a84`bf4ae380 fffff803`37427b0f     : ffffd607`834c9b20 ffffd607`88b83dc0 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`8acfb200 : nt!ExpInterlockedPopEntrySListFault
ffff9a84`bf4ae390 fffff803`37bb5094     : 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`8b199a40 00000000`766d6777 00000000`00000000 : nt!ExAllocateHeapPool+0x49f
ffff9a84`bf4ae4d0 fffff803`4f80a9bc     : fffff803`4f89fa00 ffffd607`8ee17010 ffffd607`905c7a10 ffffd607`00000000 : nt!ExAllocatePoolWithTag+0x64
ffff9a84`bf4ae520 fffff803`4f80d7b2     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`bf4ae5b8 ffffd607`8ee17010 00000000`0000000a : nwifi!Dot11AllocateRecvPacket+0x90
ffff9a84`bf4ae560 fffff803`4f80e533     : ffffd607`8a000302 ffffd607`00000030 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 : nwifi!Pt6RepackRecvNBL+0xa2
ffff9a84`bf4ae600 fffff803`3bc67ef0     : ffffd607`8f2a3c30 fffff803`4f80e3b0 ffffd607`887d5020 00000000`00000001 : nwifi!Pt6Receive+0x183
ffff9a84`bf4ae660 fffff803`3bc9df58     : ffffd607`8acf8700 ffff9a84`bf4ae731 ffffd607`8acf8530 fffff804`ae77ca8b : ndis!ndisCallReceiveHandler+0x60
ffff9a84`bf4ae6b0 fffff803`3bc64a94     : 00000000`00114631 00000000`00000001 ffffd607`839b71a0 00000000`00000001 : ndis!ndisInvokeNextReceiveHandler+0x148
ffff9a84`bf4ae780 fffff804`ae7b1296     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`8c224d80 00000000`0000000a : ndis!NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x104
ffff9a84`bf4ae810 fffff804`ae77d325     : ffffd607`8b8b9118 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`bf4ae901 ffffd607`8b3c8b10 : Netwbw02!doApiIndicateReceiveNbl+0x92
ffff9a84`bf4ae850 fffff804`ae7c8742     : ffffd607`0000000a 00000029`2f6c5767 ffffd607`90eceb30 00000029`2f6c5767 : Netwbw02!prvRxDataHandlePhyHdrFrames+0x715
ffff9a84`bf4ae8b0 fffff804`ae7c0839     : ffffd607`00000000 ffffd607`8b76b8ff 00000000`00000000 fffff803`374125df : Netwbw02!rfdQueueProcessFragments+0x1e2
ffff9a84`bf4ae950 fffff804`ae7b7598     : 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`8b76b8a0 ffffd607`839b71a0 00000000`00000000 : Netwbw02!isrHandlerRoutine+0x221
ffff9a84`bf4ae9b0 fffff804`ae7a9192     : 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`834a8060 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`bf4aeaa1 : Netwbw02!alonExInterruptHandlerRoutine+0x1c
ffff9a84`bf4ae9e0 fffff803`3bcc6df8     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`834b5180 : Netwbw02!oscHandleInterrupt+0x12
ffff9a84`bf4aea10 fffff803`3bcc72ec     : ffffd607`8b76bb88 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisMiniportDpc+0xf0
ffff9a84`bf4aeaa0 fffff803`3bcb7dfb     : ffffd607`834a8040 ffffd607`834a8040 ffff9a84`bf4aeba9 fffff803`3bc97100 : ndis!ndisQueuedMiniportDpcWorkItem+0x11c
ffff9a84`bf4aeb40 fffff803`37471d25     : ffffd607`834b5040 ffffd607`834b5040 fffff803`3bc97130 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisReceiveWorkerThread+0x20ccb
ffff9a84`bf4aec10 fffff803`37601f08     : fffff803`33f87180 ffffd607`834b5040 fffff803`37471cd0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
ffff9a84`bf4aec60 00000000`00000000     : ffff9a84`bf4af000 ffff9a84`bf4a9000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x28


SYMBOL_NAME:  nwifi!Dot11AllocateRecvPacket+90

MODULE_NAME: nwifi

IMAGE_NAME:  nwifi.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  90

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_nwifi!Dot11AllocateRecvPacket

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {10acb27e-cf1f-e7d3-8b3d-9ec902e8eafb}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above.
Arg2: 0000000000001e00, The watchdog period (in ticks).
Arg3: fffff80337efb320, cast to nt!DPC_WATCHDOG_GLOBAL_TRIAGE_BLOCK, which contains
    additional information regarding the cumulative timeout
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: TickPeriods                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 5077

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 5084

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 14

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 23

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 8468

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 1438739

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 113

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.DumpHeader
    Value: 0x133

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.KiBugCheckData
    Value: 0x133

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.Register
    Value: 0x133

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY.DMP

BUGCHECK_CODE:  133

BUGCHECK_P1: 1

BUGCHECK_P2: 1e00

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff80337efb320

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

TRAP_FRAME:  ffff9a84bf4ae1f0 -- (.trap 0xffff9a84bf4ae1f0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=00000001d20c0002 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffff80337e59740
rdx=fffffffffffffff0 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80337602907 rsp=ffff9a84bf4ae380 rbp=ffff9a84bf4ae471
 r8=fffffffffffffff0  r9=0000000000000000 r10=fffff80337e59740
r11=ffff8dffc5000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
nt!ExpInterlockedPopEntrySListFault:
fffff803`37602907 498b08          mov     rcx,qword ptr [r8] ds:ffffffff`fffffff0=????????????????
Resetting default scope

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff803`3c67ee18 fffff803`3765bf02     : 00000000`00000133 00000000`00000001 00000000`00001e00 fffff803`37efb320 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff803`3c67ee20 fffff803`374d2973     : 00002d47`78984ce4 fffff803`33f87180 00000000`00000000 fffff803`33f87180 : nt!KeAccumulateTicks+0x186d32
fffff803`3c67ee80 fffff803`374d245a     : fffff803`37ef3880 ffff9a84`bf4adf00 fffff803`3ca8d800 00000000`0000a201 : nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x453
fffff803`3c67ef30 fffff803`37408a45     : fffff803`37ef3880 fffff803`3c67ef40 00000000`00000010 ffff959c`76c911b0 : nt!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine+0x1a
fffff803`3c67ef60 fffff803`375fb26a     : ffff9a84`bf4adf00 fffff803`37ef3880 00000000`00000200 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xa5
fffff803`3c67efb0 fffff803`375fba37     : fffff71b`f5e422c0 fffff803`3752300a ffff9a84`00000000 ffffffff`fffffff0 : nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xfa
ffff9a84`bf4ade80 fffff803`3760d3ad     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`bf4ae270 ffffffff`ffffffd2 fffff803`3743962f : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37
ffff9a84`bf4ae010 fffff803`37608ebd     : fffff803`37e59740 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0x6d
ffff9a84`bf4ae1f0 fffff803`37602907     : fffff803`37e59740 fffff803`37427b0f ffffd607`834c9b20 ffffd607`88b83dc0 : nt!KiPageFault+0x43d
ffff9a84`bf4ae380 fffff803`37427b0f     : ffffd607`834c9b20 ffffd607`88b83dc0 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`8acfb200 : nt!ExpInterlockedPopEntrySListFault
ffff9a84`bf4ae390 fffff803`37bb5094     : 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`8b199a40 00000000`766d6777 00000000`00000000 : nt!ExAllocateHeapPool+0x49f
ffff9a84`bf4ae4d0 fffff803`4f80a9bc     : fffff803`4f89fa00 ffffd607`8ee17010 ffffd607`905c7a10 ffffd607`00000000 : nt!ExAllocatePoolWithTag+0x64
ffff9a84`bf4ae520 fffff803`4f80d7b2     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`bf4ae5b8 ffffd607`8ee17010 00000000`0000000a : nwifi!Dot11AllocateRecvPacket+0x90
ffff9a84`bf4ae560 fffff803`4f80e533     : ffffd607`8a000302 ffffd607`00000030 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 : nwifi!Pt6RepackRecvNBL+0xa2
ffff9a84`bf4ae600 fffff803`3bc67ef0     : ffffd607`8f2a3c30 fffff803`4f80e3b0 ffffd607`887d5020 00000000`00000001 : nwifi!Pt6Receive+0x183
ffff9a84`bf4ae660 fffff803`3bc9df58     : ffffd607`8acf8700 ffff9a84`bf4ae731 ffffd607`8acf8530 fffff804`ae77ca8b : ndis!ndisCallReceiveHandler+0x60
ffff9a84`bf4ae6b0 fffff803`3bc64a94     : 00000000`00114631 00000000`00000001 ffffd607`839b71a0 00000000`00000001 : ndis!ndisInvokeNextReceiveHandler+0x148
ffff9a84`bf4ae780 fffff804`ae7b1296     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`8c224d80 00000000`0000000a : ndis!NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x104
ffff9a84`bf4ae810 fffff804`ae77d325     : ffffd607`8b8b9118 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`bf4ae901 ffffd607`8b3c8b10 : Netwbw02!doApiIndicateReceiveNbl+0x92
ffff9a84`bf4ae850 fffff804`ae7c8742     : ffffd607`0000000a 00000029`2f6c5767 ffffd607`90eceb30 00000029`2f6c5767 : Netwbw02!prvRxDataHandlePhyHdrFrames+0x715
ffff9a84`bf4ae8b0 fffff804`ae7c0839     : ffffd607`00000000 ffffd607`8b76b8ff 00000000`00000000 fffff803`374125df : Netwbw02!rfdQueueProcessFragments+0x1e2
ffff9a84`bf4ae950 fffff804`ae7b7598     : 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`8b76b8a0 ffffd607`839b71a0 00000000`00000000 : Netwbw02!isrHandlerRoutine+0x221
ffff9a84`bf4ae9b0 fffff804`ae7a9192     : 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`834a8060 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`bf4aeaa1 : Netwbw02!alonExInterruptHandlerRoutine+0x1c
ffff9a84`bf4ae9e0 fffff803`3bcc6df8     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffd607`834b5180 : Netwbw02!oscHandleInterrupt+0x12
ffff9a84`bf4aea10 fffff803`3bcc72ec     : ffffd607`8b76bb88 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisMiniportDpc+0xf0
ffff9a84`bf4aeaa0 fffff803`3bcb7dfb     : ffffd607`834a8040 ffffd607`834a8040 ffff9a84`bf4aeba9 fffff803`3bc97100 : ndis!ndisQueuedMiniportDpcWorkItem+0x11c
ffff9a84`bf4aeb40 fffff803`37471d25     : ffffd607`834b5040 ffffd607`834b5040 fffff803`3bc97130 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisReceiveWorkerThread+0x20ccb
ffff9a84`bf4aec10 fffff803`37601f08     : fffff803`33f87180 ffffd607`834b5040 fffff803`37471cd0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
ffff9a84`bf4aec60 00000000`00000000     : ffff9a84`bf4af000 ffff9a84`bf4a9000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x28


SYMBOL_NAME:  nwifi!Dot11AllocateRecvPacket+90

MODULE_NAME: nwifi

IMAGE_NAME:  nwifi.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  90

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_nwifi!Dot11AllocateRecvPacket

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {10acb27e-cf1f-e7d3-8b3d-9ec902e8eafb}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

**What next?**

Well, this is up to you to write. I am now surviving with Wi-Fi, which is not very stable. I am on a dual-boot machine and noticed that I can connect to Ethernet in Ubuntu, so I may switch to Ubuntu. I like it, but I am sometimes annoyed when I have to edit word docs in ubuntu.

In the debugging file I noticed that DPC_Watchdog was mentioned, so I gave a look over the web how to solve this issue, and found some suggestions [here](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/dpc-watchdog-violation.html), but before trying completely random things I would like to hear if someone has some nice suggestion.

Comment: Try a USB LAN Network card and disable the inbuilt card. See if that works.

Comment: Use Windows DISM and SFC utilities to fix any system file issues before making changes yourself. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image

Comment: The first thing I would do is update your system to Windows 21H2 or Windows 10 22H2 it appears your running a severely out of date version of Windows that’s not supported by Microsoft (it’s about 18 months out of date)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks. DISM didn't find any issue. SFC found and fixed some issues, but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @John, thanks. This is one next step. I will borrow or buy one USB LAN Network card.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks. I am currently updating. I was naively relying on the automatic mandatory updates, and never manually checked non mandatory ones. And that's why I ended up with an 18 months out of date version!

Comment: Realtek NICs are notoriously bad - I would suspect a driver related issue.  The problem is very unlikely to be IP address related. The OS should not crash if there are IP issues.

Comment: I replaced all mentions of “cable” with “Ethernet” to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Outdated windows isn't always the problem to this.  I would find out what drivers are available for your laptop, see if there are updates.  Realtek drivers you can also update manually directly from their website, in case you have an older laptop.  Your BSOD could be caused by a management app or something executing a routine after connecting via LAN

Comment: The BSOD appears to have been caused by the WiFi driver. Try disabling the WiFi adapter in Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem... well... more or less.
This means that I was able to make the BSOD disappear, but I don't know exactly what was going on.
Basically, in my place of work we can use static IP (causing BSOD on my PC), DHCP (causing BSOD on my PC), and a captive portal. I asked the IT department to activate for me a socket for the captive portal and... well, I am now connected via Ethernet since 2 hours!
I do not know enough about IT to understand the reason. I guess that the problematic protocol causing BSOD is not used when running via the captive portal.
I am happy with this solution (for the time being). I am available to perform some tests if someone wants to understand what's going on: this, if my IT guys did not deactivate DHCP from all my ethernet sockets.